# MERN stack save images on server and save the path in mongoDB

Tags: reactjs, image, express, path, upload

I have a create-react-app named front that sends some images to my express server. here is the structure of my project:
[my project's structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5m5Z.png)

I send images from the React app to the server using the express-fileupload module and it works fine. now I want to store the image in a folder on the server and save the path to the image in the database.

Is it possible to save the images to the public folder of the react app inside the express app? Given that they are in two different folders.

Or I should save the images inside of the express app? in this case how should I show the images in my react app and what would be the path saved in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before saving files you can add the following middleware route before all routes to serve images for the URL to frontend app. Considering this code is in same directory which has public folder.

```
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public/images')));
```

To manage the uploaded file

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
      // on frontend the input tag as name 'uploadFile'
      // as -> <input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
      let uploadFile = req.files.uploadFile;

      // e.g. "/images/myImage.jpg"
      // To be served later as http://yourdomain.com/images/myImage.jpg
      const imageUrl = `/images/${uploadFile.name}`;

      // move from temp location to your server's public/images directory
      uploadFile
            .mv(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'images', uploadFile.name))
            .then(() => {
                  // perform database save operation here and then give appropriate response
                  res.json({ message: 'File uploaded', imageUrl: imageUrl });
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
});
```

The image will be stored in public/images folder.

You might need to modify the path given to mv() function if this piece of code is not in same directory which contains public folder.

For more info, visit [here](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload/tree/master/example#basic-file-upload)